# Search Custom Post Types in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to search only by a custom post type in Wordpress.

In my search form I have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="customposttype" />
```

In my functions file I have:

```
 function template_chooser($template)   
 {    
  global $wp_query;   
  $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');   
  if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'customposttype' )  
   {
    return locate_template('customposttype-search.php'); 
    }   
  return $template;   
  }
add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
```

This gets me to the right search template. However, I'm still getting ALL WordPress results in the actual search results. Do I need to modify:

```
<?php if( have_posts()){ ?>
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
...
```

somehow too in my "customposttype-search.php"?

Comment: Yes! I did. I needed:

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did:

I needed

```
<?php if($post->post_type == 'customposttype' ){ ?>
```

On the next line. Several sources I've seen omit that.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, do you use the main loop or is there a call to `query_posts`?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be easier just to use pre get posts and alter the query to search only for the choosen custom post type? Something like this :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_search', 9999 );
function custom_post_type_search( $query ) {
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return;
}

if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
}

if( ! $query->is_search() ) {
    return;
}
$is_custom_post_type_search = isset( $_GET['customposttype'] );
if ( ! $is_course_search ) {
    return;
}
$query->set( 'post_type', $is_custom_post_type_search );
return $query;
}
```